# Error when executing line, outside loop in Python Interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I was trying some stuff out in the python interpreter [3.10] and wanted to execute a for loop:

If I execute the following code on python:

```
>>> for i in range(4):
...     print(i, end = ': ')
... print('\n')
```

I get an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print('\n')
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However if I execute the same code in ipython, there are no errors:

```
In [1]: for i in range(4):
   ...:     print(i, end = ': ')
   ...: print('\n')
```

Output:

```
0: 1: 2: 3:
```

Comment: This is a quirk of the interactive shell. You need to enter a blank line to tell the shell that the loop is finished, before proceeding to write more lines of code.

Comment: But if I enter a blank line, the loop gets executed and I end up with the prompt on the same line, as follows:

0: 1: 2: 3: >>>

Comment: @N00B_141 Such it the behavior of the built in REPL. If you want IPython's extended multi-line support, you'll need to use IPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must only give the python interpreter one statement at a time.

This might be a code block, in which case it will wait for you to dedent before executing.

But including the second statement `print('\n')` is invalid input.

On the other hand, in a Python program, executed from a file, you can have multiple statements.   This accounts for the difference in behavior.

In short:   provide an extra return before `print('\n')` so the interpreter can execute your first statement before you move on to the next.

Comment: Oooh, that's an interesting quirk! But why does it work on ipython though?

Answer (score -2):

I think you are using python 2.x version in your system, that's why you are facing this issue. Please check your python version by this command.

```
python --version
```

if you have python version "2.x" you need to use this code snippet for performing same operation

```
for i in range(4):
    print i, ':',
print '\n'
```

If you have python "3.x" version, you can use same code snippet, which you have provided.

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i, end=': ')
print('\n')
```

Comment: No, as stated they are using Python 3.10, and that snippet _does_ produce a syntax error in Python 3.10 when pasted into the interactive prompt.

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Please do note use your answers to advertise your personal help services. I've edited out the advertisement under the assumption that it wasn't intentional spam.

Comment: sorry recently i started on stack overflow, so i don't know about this. From next time i will keep this thing in my mind